# How to save photos from old Samsung AT&T flip phone with white screen (corrupted gpu) to my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, photos, graphics, data-transfer, gpu

I have some precious photos (family children) and sounds (baby voices) stored on my old Samsung AT&T SGH-a687 phone, not the SD card, that is experiencing a white screen of death after about a week of graphics pixelation and stripes problems due to a bad gpu.

I'm wondering what I can do to get those information I stored on the phone out. I tried connecting the phone to my MacBook Pro (I also have Windows if that's easier), but I can't get anything out. So I'm wondering what I can do to salvage those photos. How do I get these photos out onto my computer?

Comment: When you say "I can't get anything out", do you mean the phone is never mounted (shows up on the desktop) or that no data appears to be present on the phone?

Comment: The data is on the phone, but I don't know how to get it on my computer.

Comment: I mean, does your MacBook "see" your phone when you plug it in? You should see something that looks like a flash drive on the desktop or in the sidebar of Finder.

Comment: It does not "see" my phone.